# Universal typescript npm module

Tags: typescript, npm, es6-modules, umd

I am modifying an existing library so it can be imported in typescript. I've boiled it down to a [Minimal working example](https://github.com/Sobotkama/umd-experiment)

## The requirements

- To remain backwards compatible, the library needs to be importable with a simple `<script>` tag
- To simplify future usage, the library needs to be importable with a single typescript `import` statement (no `<script>` tags in HTML should be needed)
- I have used rollup, but solutions using any other way to achieve this result (gulp, webpack, etc.) are welcome too.

## What I've got so far

### Library

File structure:

```
│   package.json
│   rollup.config.js
│   tsconfig.json
│   yarn-error.log
│   yarn.lock
│
└───src
        lib.ts
        options.ts
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "library",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "description": "example library",
  "main": "dist/lib.umd.js",
  "module":"dist/lib.esm.js",
  "types":"dist/types/lib.d.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.0",
    "rollup": "^2.67.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "exports": {
    "import": "./dist/lib.esm.js",
    "require": "./dist/lib.umd.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:types": "tsc -d --emitDeclarationOnly",
    "build:js": "rollup -c rollup.config.js",
    "build:minjs:umd": "terser dist/index.umd.js --compress --mangle > dist/index.umd.min.js",
    "build:minjs:esm": "terser dist/index.esm.js --compress --mangle > dist/index.esm.min.js",
    "build:minjs": "npm run build:minjs:esm -s && npm run build:minjs:umd -s",
    "build": "npm run build:js -s && npm run build:minjs -s && npm run build:types -s",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run lint -s && npm test -s && npm run build",
    "semantic-release": "semantic-release"
  },
  "type":"module"
}
```

`rollup.config.js`:

```js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default {
  input: 'src/lib.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: 'dist/lib.esm.js',
      format: 'es',
    },
    {
      file: 'dist/lib.umd.js',
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'Lib',
    },
  ],
  plugins: [typescript({tsconfig:'./tsconfig.json'})],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./types",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```

`src/lib.ts`:

```
import Options from "./options";

export default class Lib{
    constructor(options:Options){
        console.log("It works!");
        console.log(options.message);
    }
}
```

`options.ts`:

```
export default interface Options {
    message: string;
}
```

I am compiling all of this using `yarn build:js`.

### Using the library

#### With `<script>` tags

When I copy the resulting `lib.umd.js` to a folder and create a `index.html`:

```html
<script src=lib.umd.js></script>
<script>
    var a = new Lib({message:"message here"});
</script>
```

It works. So far so good.

#### In another typescript project

Next, I created a simple typescript project that utilizes my library.

File structure:

```
│   gulpfile.js
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.json
│   yarn.lock
│
├───dist
│       index.html
│
└───Scripts
        Index.ts
```

In `package.json` I include my library as a dependency, along with jQuery to hopefully rule out improper configuration of this project:

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npx use-yarn",
        "gulp": "node_modules/.bin/gulp"
    },
    "name": "ts-import",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.13",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
        "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
        "typescript": "^4.5.5",
        "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "*",
        "library": "file:../../library"
    }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir":"./js"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "include":[
        "./Scripts"
    ]
}
```

I'm using gulp to compile ts and resolve imports - `gulpfile.js`:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const {series} = require('gulp');
const clean = require('gulp-clean');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

function cleanAll(cb) {
  return gulp.src([
      "./tmp/",
      "./dist/js"
    ], { read: false, allowEmpty: true })
    .pipe(clean());
}

function transpileTS() {
  const tsproject = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');
  return tsproject
      .src()
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(tsproject()).js
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./sourcemaps'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/js'));
}

function minJS() {
  return gulp
      .src('./tmp/js/Index.js')
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(browserify())
    //   .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat('index.min.js'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./sourcemaps'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
}

exports.default = series( cleanAll, transpileTS, minJS );
```

I'm importing and using my library like this - `Scripts/Index.ts`:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import Lib from "library";

$(()=>{
    console.log("creating lib instance.");
    new Lib({message:"example message here"});
});
```

But when I launch this in a browser - `dist/index.html`:

```
<script src="js/Index.min.js"></script>
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: library_1.default is not a constructor
```

Indeed, `library_1.default` doesn't exist, `library_1` does though:

```js
> library_1
< class Lib {
        constructor(options) {
            console.log("It works!");
            console.log(options.message);
        }
    }
```

How do I fix this? I suspect the error is somewhere in the library, but I have no idea where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.
In my `lib.ts` I had to change the way I export my class:

```js
import Options from "./options";

class Lib{
    constructor(options:Options){
        console.log("It works!");
        console.log(options.message);
    }
}

export default Lib;
```

Next, I changed `rollup.config.js` (added `exports:'default'`) to keep the exported class global:

```js
...
{
      file: 'dist/lib.umd.js',
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'Lib',
      exports:'default'
},
...
```

I also had to change the library's `package.json` - I pointed `main` to my es module as it looks like browserify just ignores the module directive.
I also ended up removing the `exports` section as some of our other projects (not using browserify) kept using the `require` file, not the `import` one:

```json
{
  "name": "library",
  "version": "1.0.16",
  "description": "example library",
  "main": "dist/lib.esm.js",
  "module":"dist/lib.esm.js",
  "types":"dist/types/lib.d.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.0",
    "rollup": "^2.67.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "exports": {
    "import": "./dist/lib.esm.js",
    "require": "./dist/lib.umd.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c rollup.config.js"
  }
}
```

Finally, I had to use babelify in my consumer project to avoid `ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'` while running browserify.

The full source is available [here](https://github.com/Sobotkama/umd-experiment)